# is there a nice way to find the fourier transform of...

Tags: analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

I am looking for a nice way to calculate the FT of the following function

$f(x)=\biggl(\sum_{n=1}^{c}~a_n~e^{-\frac{i}{2}~x~b_n}\biggr)^d$,

where $d,c>0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real coefficients, strictly monotonously rising in $n$ and $x$ is the free variable and $c$ might go to $\infty$.

I used mathematica to calculate it, but without specification of $d$ and when $c\to\infty$, there is no way that the programme will do it.

Any helpful ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure $f$ is integrable? And is $d$ an integer?

Comment: it is from a physics book. it seems the author does not worry to much about the dirichlet conditions.

Comment: And how is the Fourier transform defined?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}~dx~f(x)~e^{ikx}$ is not given.

Comment: What's the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: What is the name of the physics book you got it from?

Comment: its from a statistical mechanics book. i know well that usually one wouldnt compute it straightforwardly. there is a similar one with $f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^d \frac{e^{-ix/2}}{1-e^{-ix}}$. It is said that it is computed with the "saddlepoint method", which is then done. It refers to de Bruijn,asymptotic methods in analysis and morese, feshbach methods in theoretical physics. I cant apply these techniques to the given function.

Comment: the domain of x should be going from 0 till infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ is a positive integer, then you can use the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) to expand your expression then take the Fourier transform with the appropriate condition on  $\sum b_k $.

Comment: ahh. so this would give me some sort of a comb of delta-distributions, right?

Comment: If $d$ is not an integer, it looks rather difficult...

Comment: If $d$ is a positive integer, expand $f$ as $f(x) = \sum_{n_1} \cdots \sum_{n_d} a_{n_1} \cdots a_{n_d} e^{\frac{i}{2} x (b_{n_1}+ \cdots + b_{n_d})}$,
and then, formally, $\hat{f}(\omega) = \sum_{n_1} \cdots \sum_{n_d} a_{n_1} \cdots a_{n_d} \delta(\omega - \frac{b_{n_1}+ \cdots + b_{n_d}}{2})$.

Comment: right. d is supposed to be an integer. i accidentally forgot to note it down.

Comment: so this is what i meant with the comb of dirac deltas. if d was $\infty$ the comb is quite dense. can i use this in any sense?

Comment: @Hamurabi:Didn't I gave you the idea and the steps to solve your problem in my answer?

Comment: @Mhenni. Sure. I got it. and its right. the multinomial theorem is a nice trick. i just wanted to know, if I can make something from the delta comb. thats all.

Comment: @Hamurabi:It has uses in electrical engineering. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb)